# How do I change the color of an active link in a ul using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

I'm trying to change the font color of the active li item. I've tried, as per other posts on this site:

```
$("li").click(function() {
$("li").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");    ​
```

And I have this - [Active Link](http://jsfiddle.net/phUhb/5/) - on jsfiddle.

The other element attributes change, but not the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS should be:

```
.active a { ... }
```

not just .active like so : http://jsfiddle.net/phUhb/19/

Comment: Okay, so if it _doesn't_ work, what gives? I added more to this: http://jsfiddle.net/phUhb/34/ and it works there, but not on my site. Or is this something I'm going to have to dig through myself...

Comment: Unless I see everything, You'll have to dig it up yourself. If it's not working on yours site then it sounds like there's another CSS rule overriding it.

Comment: This is very bad for a live setting but you can add a !important at the end of your style... like this: http://jsfiddle.net/phUhb/36/ Try that on your live site and if it works after that then it's definitely another styling overriding.

Comment: I got it. The problem was how I was setting styles to the elements. The div styling was nested in the li styling, so it reverted. I applied all styling to the li and removed the nested div.

Answer (score 0):

It´s not working because the entire code in your website is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("li").click(function() {
    $("li").removeClass("actives");
    $(this).addClass("actives");
});
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain how that code makes it not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
      debugger;
      var path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
      if (path == '')
           path = "page1.aspx";
      var target = $('.ul a[href,"' + path + '"]');
      target = $(this).a(active);
 });
```

Is it correct?